# How to get an individual row in Big Query?

Tags: python, sql, pandas, google-bigquery

I want to get an individual row from the QueryJob in BQ. My query: `select count(*) from ...` returns a single row & I want to read the count value which is its first column. So if I can get the first row then I can do `row[0]` for the first column. I can iterate: `row in queryJob` but since I require only the first row this seems unneccesary.

Below is what I've tried:

```
row = self.client.query(count_query)
count = row.result()[0]
```

This gives an error:

```
'QueryJob' object is not subscriptable"
```

How can I get individual rows from queryJob by the row index?

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
row = self.client.query(count_query)
result = row.result().total_rows
```

This will give the count from the query

Answer (score 0):

you can use [**`to_dataframe()`**](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/samples/bigquery-query-results-dataframe):

```
result = self.client.query(count_query).to_dataframe()

#if you want to result as a integer:
result = self.client.query(count_query).to_dataframe()['first_column_name'].iat[0]
```